# What precisely are the differences between היתר מצטרף לאיסור and טעם כעיקר?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, nozir, issur-vheter

Learning maseches nozir around daf 35, I encountered two concepts:

היתר מצטרף לאיסור (HML)
and
טעם כעיקר (TK)

**HML**

The [Gemoro 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.35b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) indicates that HML is derived from [Bamidbar 6(3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.3?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

> מִיַּ֤יִן וְשֵׁכָר֙ יַזִּ֔יר חֹ֥מֶץ יַ֛יִן וְחֹ֥מֶץ שֵׁכָ֖ר לֹ֣א
> יִשְׁתֶּ֑ה וְכָל־מִשְׁרַ֤ת עֲנָבִים֙ לֹ֣א יִשְׁתֶּ֔ה וַעֲנָבִ֛ים
> לַחִ֥ים וִיבֵשִׁ֖ים לֹ֥א יֹאכֵֽל׃
>
> he shall abstain from wine and any other intoxicant; he shall not
> drink vinegar of wine or of any other intoxicant, neither shall he
> drink anything in which grapes have been steeped, nor eat grapes fresh
> or dried.

This verse indicates that a nazirite gets punished from consuming not only wine and vinegar, but also any food that was soaked in these liquids.

This is because the food which is permitted combines with the (forbidden) liquid to make the requisite quantity.

**TK**

[The Gemoro Pesachim 44b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.44a.14?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) seems to derive the principle of TK from the same possuk,

> והאי משרת להכי הוא דאתא האי מיבעי ליה לכדתניא משרת ליתן טעם כעיקר שאם
> שרה ענבים במים ויש בהן טעם יין חייב מכאן
>
> The word  משרת comes to teach that if the nazirite steeped grapes in
> water and the water took on the taste of wine, the nazirite would be
> liable to punishment.

So it seems that the concepts are very similar.

What precisely are the differences between היתר מצטרף לאיסור and טעם כעיקר ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rashi in Pesachim defines the two concepts, and stresses the differences between them:

[Rashi on Pesachim 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Pesachim.43b.12.1?lang=bi):

> אכל חצי זית חלב וחצי זית בשר בבת אחת אין היתר משלים את שיעור האיסור לחייבו חוץ מאיסורי נזיר שאם אכל חצי זית ענבים וחצי זית לחם בבת אחת חייב
>
> If one eats half a *kezayit* of *chelev* and half a *kezayit* of meat at the same time, the permitted food does not combine with the measure of forbidden food to make him liable, apart from the case of a *nazir*, where, if he eats half a *kezayit* of grapes and half a *kezayit* of bread at the same time, he is liable.

[Rashi on Pesachim 44b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Pesachim.44b.1.1?lang=bi):

> ליתן טעם כעיקר - לעשות טעמו של איסור כעיקרו וממשו:,ויש בהן - במים טעם יין:,חייב - בכזית מהן והא לאו משום היתר מצטרף לאיסור הוא אלא משום דאיתעביד ליה כוליה איסור
>
> To apply *ta'am keikar* - to equate forbidden taste with the actual food itself. If the water has the taste of wine, he is liable if he drinks a *kezayit* of it. This is not because of *heter mitztaref le-issur*, rather that the whole item becomes forbidden.

Note further that the Gemara points out that these are two competing derivations. R. Akiva learns *heter mitztaref le-issur* and applies it only to *nazir*. The other Sages learn *ta'am ke-ikar* and apply the principle to all forbidden foods.

The way Rashi explains the discussion, *heter mitztaref le-issur* is a specific rule for a *nazir* that makes you liable for eating a minute amount of forbidden food, as long as your act of eating involved a total amount of a *kezayit*, seemingly even if the two foodstuffs do not form a mixture. *Ta'am ke-ikar*, on the other hand, means that in the case of a permitted food suffused with forbidden taste, the entire item is defined as forbidden food, owing to the presence of forbidden taste.

[Ba'al HaMaor](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46678&st=&pgnum=341) on the *sugya* seems to understand *heter mitztaref leissur* very similarly to Rashi's approach, but he believes that *ta'am ke-ikar* only applies if you have an entire *kezayit* of forbidden food dissolved into the permitted food, and one eats the whole *kezayit* of dissolved forbidden food within *kedei achilat p'ras*.

This, he stresses, is very different from *heter mitztaref le-issur*, where eating even half a *kezayit* of forbidden food together with half a *kezayit* of permitted food, makes one liable (in the case of *nazir*).